# Why is a variable not an lvalue in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, type-traits

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{    
    int n;
    n = 0;

    // failure!
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(n)>); 
}
```

`n` can be put on the left side, so it should be obviously an lvalue.

**Why does the `static_assert` fail?**

Comment: because `int` type is not a reference? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_lvalue_reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) has special rules for id-expressions, deducing their type without regard to value category. If you want it to deduce a type based on the value category an id-expression normally has, you can surround the id-expression in parenthesis:

```
static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype((n))>);
```

`(n)` has the same type and value category as `n` in the type system, but isn't treated specially by `decltype`. Since the expression is an lvalue, the deduced type will be of an lvalue reference type.

Comment: This confuses me, I get that `n` is an lvalue, but how is it an lvalue _reference_? What if I made a `int & j` what kind of lvalue is that then?

Comment: @Frodyne - It's not an lvalue reference, it's an `int`. But `n` is also an expression, and as an expression it has a type and value category. Its value category is an lvalue. So far so good, but `decltype` tries to fold the value category into the deduced type. For lvalue expressions of type `T` it will provide the type `T&`.

Comment: `decltype(auto) f() { int n; return (n); }` returns a (dangling) reference. Is that related and if so, how?

Comment: @Aconcagua - It is related. `decltype(auto)` deduces the return type from the `expr` in `return expr;`. Since it's parenthesized, it uses the rules which deduce a reference type for most lvalue expressions. If it wasn't parenthesized, it would have used the special rule for id-expressions, that just gives their declared type.

Comment: Hm, always considered the parenthesised case the 'special case'??? Can you provide a concrete example where the non-parenthesised argument produces a reference even though the l-value itself wasn't one (`T` -> `T&` in your response to @Frodyne)?

Comment: @Aconcagua - For any pointer, `*p` is an expression whose type is `T` and is an lvalue. So `decltype` will yield `T&`.

Answer (score 2):

`n` is indeed an lvalue reference, but `decltype(n)` returns `int`, and not `int&`. This mechanism is based on the way template type deduction works. It allows you such declarations and initializations:

```
int n = 0;

decltype(n) m = 42;
```

If `decltype(n)` were to yield `int&`, the above snippet wouldn't even compile. You can hence make the compiler happy with

```
static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(n)&>); 
static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<decltype(n)>>);
```

but I guess this was not the point in the first place.